# Do I need a business visa for Ireland if I already have Standard Visitor visa for UK?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel, family

I currently have a UK visitor (category: Family) visa for 10 years, which I received in Nov 2015.

I need to attend a meeting in Dublin, Ireland for a week and want to find out if I can use my existing visa for this purpose?

As I understand, both business and family visa's have been consolidated under the Standard Visitor visa (although categories are still mentioned, the type of visa listed on my passport is "C"). Hoping I don't need to get a new visa.

Comment: What is your nationality? What is actually shown on the visa?

Answer (score 7):

UK visit visas issued prior to April 2015 were segmented along the lines of 'business', 'family', 'academic' and so on.  The [Immigration Act 2014](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/407476/HC_1025_Immigration_Rules.pdf) changed all of that and consolidated all visitor visas (which are technically known as 'entry clearances') into the single 'Standard Visitor Visa'...

> This is the single consolidated UK visa type that covers all aspects
>   where a person comes to the UK for tourism, visiting family/friends,
>   job interviews, business trips, some forms of academic research, some
>   forms of volunteer work, and group travel. It is uniformly multiple
>   entry. This visa was created by the Immigration Act 2014 and has
>   existed since April 2015. The 'Standard Visitor Visa' is a subset of
>   the more generic UK 'entry clearance'.

(our tag definition for [standard-visitor-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/standard-visitor-visa/info))

On 20 March 2015, the Home Office sent an advisory to the UK legal community explaining the changes. Inexplicably, they did not put this advisory on the net, but here's a screen cap of the relevant portion...

[image]

So you can use your 10 year entry clearance for any permitted activity listed in [Appendix V of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).

In your case *you can use your family visit visa to attend a business conference*. Note that the reverse case (a business visitor wanting to engage in tourist activities) [is already taken up in this site's archives](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51768/visit-uk-like-a-tourist-with-c-visit-business/51780#51780).

See also: [Entering UK for leisure while holding a business visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40396/entering-uk-for-leisure-while-holding-a-business-visa)

For the other part of your question, Ireland is not in the UK or the Commonwealth, but it *is* in the [Common Travel Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area) (CTA) and this is an open border arrangement.  If you use a UK entry clearance to move within the CTA, (Ireland, Isle of Man, Guernsey, and so on), it's *assumed* that you have a local visa valid for seven days. The same goes for anyone issued a visa by a CTA member who comes to the UK, 7 days, unless they have a visa issued by the ROI, and in that case it's 3 months.

So your visit to the ROI is limited to 7 days.

Note: In anticipation of future questions, let me add that a Standard Visitor Visa can also be used in place of a UK Transit Visa.

Note: regarding the part about emailing the policy team, they will not engage with people unless the person is authorised and qualified under Sections 84 and 85 of the [Immigration and Asylum Act 1999](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1999/33/contents).  That's why people complain that their emails are "ignored" when they ask about the Standard Visitor Visa. Hence this question can only be answered here and other sites (like forums and [Colin Yeo's site](https://www.freemovement.org.uk/new-immigration-rules-for-visitors-to-the-united-kingdom/)).